# Scalar function that returns Address

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've updated the code as suggested, but now I'm getting a new error:

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udf_GetCustomerAddress, Line 31
>   A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

My code is pasted below:

```
--The function
Create Function udf_GetCustomerAddress
    (@CustomerID varchar)
Returns varchar
As
Begin
    declare @CustomerAddress varchar

    select 
        @CustomerAddress = c.CompanyName, c.Address, c.City, 
        c.StateOrRegion, c.PostalCode, c.CustomerID
    from 
        Customers c
    where 
        c.CustomerID = @CustomerID

    Return @CustomerAddress
End
```

Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a length for all the `varchar()`s -- always use a length in SQL Server.  Then you probably want to concatenate the results.  If I assume that all types are strings . . .

```
Create Function udf_GetCustomerAddress (
    @CustomerID varchar(255)
)
Returns varchar(max)
As
Begin
    declare @CustomerAddress varchar(max);

    select @CustomerAddress = (c.CompanyName + ' ' +
                               c.Address + ' ' +
                               c.City + ' ' + 
                               c.StateOrRegion + ' ' +
                               c.PostalCode + ' ' +
                               c.CustomerID
                              )
    from Customers c
    where c.CustomerID = @CustomerID;

    Return @CustomerAddress;
End;
```

This assumes that you actually want all the fields with some separator.

However, I don't think this is the best way to get the functionality you want.  It is better to add a computed column to the table:

```
alter table Customers c
    add CustomerAddress as (<expression here>);
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Comment: When I call the function, I still get an error: 

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
The multi-part identifier "dbo.udf_GetCustomerAddress" could not becbound.

I'm calling the function like this:
select dbo.udf_GetCustomerAddress 'company ID' as 'Company Address'

Any thoughts?

Comment: @user7879707 . . . You should ask another question and show how the function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `Return varchar` by `RETURNS VARCHAR`

```
Go
--Address function
Create Function udf_GetCustomerAddress
(@CustomerID varchar)
RETURNS varchar(max)
As
Begin
    declare @CustomerAddress varchar(max);

    select @CustomerAddress = concat(c.CompanyName, c.Address, c.City, 
    c.StateOrRegion, c.PostalCode, c.CustomerID)
    from Customers c
    where c.CustomerID = @CustomerID;

    Return @CustomerAddress;
End
```

Have a look at [CREATE FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) syntax.

Comment: Thanks @McNets - appreciate it.

Comment: You would never want to use varchar(max) unless you are returning more than 8000 characters. Uncommon when dealing with addresses.